# Changing backgroundcolor for Relativelayout in setviewbinder

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android,in my app i want to change the color of my custom listview. Here is my code

```
String[] from = new String[] { Contactsnew.CONTENT};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.content123, R.id.linear123};
custAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.activity_contactitem, null, from, to);
//ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
listview.setAdapter(custAdapter);
    custAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("asda", "asd");
        if(view.getId() == R.id.linear123){
        RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linear123);
        relative.setBackgroundColor(0xFFC1E7F);
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

After running its showing a ArrayIndexoutofbounds.

Log report

```
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at        android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:131)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1566)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1205)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at  android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-13 12:44:57.004: E/AndroidRuntime(2107):     at
```

Like this i am getting.

Comment: You cannot change the question after you have answers below! The answers now looks not relevant!!!

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the variable "relative" is null. Do you have set the current view? If not -> You'll get an NPE when get a view by ID

Comment: In this method you are not setting a View ;)

Comment: hi guyz if i remove that R.id.linear123 from string[], its not showing error.but, still i m getting the old listview without any color.

Comment: from has 1 entry. to has 2 entries. So you will get an AIOOB exception

Answer (score 0):

You run the command `findViewById` on the wrong view, what you do is to find the relative layout inside the list view (which of course won't find it there anf that's why you get *null*).
findViewById searches view only under the activated object (the listview in your case).

You need to run the `findViewById` on the layout that holds the `RelativeLayout`.

If you run in a fragment, then try `getView().findViewById(...)`

Comment: i find the relative layout correctly, its showing Arrayindexoutofbounds

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand you. Did you change the code or not? Is it the same exception or not?

Comment: i have added the log report can u check it and say

Comment: Please post also your code (all the class). Are you running with an activity or fragment?

Comment: there are 10 classes and i am doing it for company i m not suppose to put all the classes.

Comment: First, delete your 'if' condition.

Second, you this line: RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout)PutHereYourClassName.this.findViewById(R.id.linear123);

Comment: hi guyz if i remove that R.id.linear123 from string[], its not showing error.but, still i m getting the old listview without any color.